# The code completion is unnecessary when the left curly brace is entered in IDEA, how to solve it？

Tags: intellij-idea

My software version is 2020.3.4！Do you have the same situation in your version?I can't search the same question on net.
[Screenshot in IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMBUy.png)

Thankyou!

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: There is too much content in the document.I think there may be a problem with the editor's configuration problem

Comment: You may try to reset settings to default (File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings)